# Using vcs_info in zsh custom prompt with promptinit

Tags: zsh, prompt, zshrc

Currently in my `.zshrc` I have the following lines to provide some git info:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd_vcs_info() { vcs_info }
precmd_functions+=( precmd_vcs_info )
setopt prompt_subst
RPROMPT=\$vcs_info_msg_0_
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'
```

This makes my shell look like the following:

```
[me@computer dir]$                                                                  main
```

I would like to move this configuration out of `.zshrc` and into a custom prompt that is initiliazed using `promptinit`. This configuration is in a file called `prompt_mycustomprompt_setup` that is available on my `fpath`. The configuration looks as follows:

```
precmd_vcs_info() {
    vcs_info
}

prompt_mycustomprompt_setup () {
    autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook vcs_info
    setopt prompt_subst
    add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_vcs_info
    RPROMPT=\$vcs_info_msg_0_
    zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'

    PS1='(test)> '
}

prompt_mycustomprompt_setup "$@"
```

I then removed the relevant lines from my `.zshrc` and replaced with the following lines:

```
autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit

prompt mycustomprompt
```

However, the vcs_info is not displayed and instead I have a constant static value of `$vcs_info_msg_0_` in my prompt:

```
(test)>                                                         $vcs_info_msg_0_
```

Why will my prompt not behave as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the statement `setopt promptsubst` in your function is executed inside the `prompt` function, which does `setopt localoptions`. So, when `prompt` returns, the option gets reset to default.

Instead of setting shell options directly, `promptinit` themes are supposed to [set the `prompt_opts` array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Writing-Themes):

> The array `prompt_opts` may be assigned any of `"bang"`, `"cr"`, `"percent"`, `"sp"`, and/or `"subst"` as values. The corresponding setopts (promptbang, etc.) are turned on, all other prompt-related options are turned off.

So, for your prompt to use `setopt promptsubst`, you should do something like this in your `setup` function:

```sh
prompt_opts=(cr percent sp subst)
```

However, as mentioned on the [Zsh mailing list](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/mlist.html), the Zsh devs generally recommend *not* to use `promptsubst`, as this can

- have side effects where you might not expect them (such as when using `print -P`) and/or
- result in poor performance (when an expression in your prompt turns out to be more expensive than expected and gets re-evaluated whenever the prompt gets redrawn).

To ensure optimal performance and stability, I would recommend doing this instead:

```sh
prompt_mycustomprompt_precmd() {
    vcs_info
    RPS1=" $vcs_info_msg_0_"
}

prompt_mycustomprompt_setup () {
    autoload -Uz vcs_info
    add-zsh-hook precmd prompt_mycustomprompt_precmd   
    zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'

    prompt_opts=( cr percent sp )
    PS1='(test)> '
}

prompt_mycustomprompt_setup "$@"
```

Note that I have also renamed your `precmd` hook function, because all `prompinit` hook function names are supposed to follow the pattern `prompt_<theme>_<hook>`, so that [the `prompt` function can automatically unhook them](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/ab166725dd5983b00cf21113fb77717c6be324c5/Functions/Prompts/promptinit#L181) when switching themes.

Additionally, `promptinit` themes are supposed to use the shorter `$PS1`, `$RPS1`, etc. instead of `$PROMPT`, `$RPROMPT`, etc.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you for such a detailed explanation too!